# Using std::move on a dereferenced shared_ptr in a concurrent queue

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, move, smart-pointers

Below is the code for a thread-safe queue in Anthony Williams' book *C++ concurrency in action* that I gathered in a `.h` file.

```
#ifndef THREADSAFE_QUEUE_H
#define THREADSAFE_QUEUE_H

// Anthony Williams' fine-grained lock-based thread-safe queue.

#include <mutex>                // for std::mutex
#include <condition_variable>   // for std::condition_variable
#include <memory>               // for std::shaerd_ptr and std::unique_ptr
#include <utility>              // for std::move


template <typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
    };

    std::mutex head_mutex;
    std::unique_ptr<node> head;
    std::mutex tail_mutex;
    node* tail;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
    threadsafe_queue():
        head(new node), tail(head.get())
    {}
    threadsafe_queue(const threadsafe_queue& other)=delete;
    threadsafe_queue& operator=(const threadsafe_queue& other)=delete;

    std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop();
    bool try_pop(T& value);
    std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop();
    void wait_and_pop(T& value);
    void push(T new_value);
    void empty();

private:
    node* get_tail()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> tail_lock(tail_mutex);
        return tail;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> pop_head()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<node> old_head = std::move(head);
        head = std::move(old_head->next);
        return old_head;
    }

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wait_for_data()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
        data_cond.wait(head_lock, [&]{return head.get()!=get_tail();});
        return std::move(head_lock);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> wait_pop_head()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(wait_for_data());
        return pop_head();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> wait_pop_head(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(wait_for_data());
        value=std::move(*head->data);
        return pop_head();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> try_pop_head()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
        if(head.get()==get_tail())
        {
            return std::unique_ptr<node>();
        }
        return pop_head();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> try_pop_head(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
        if(head.get()==get_tail())
        {
            return std::unique_ptr<node>();
        }
        value=std::move(*head->data);
        return pop_head();
    }

};

/*
 * PUBLIC INTERFACE
 */

// try pop.
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> threadsafe_queue<T>::try_pop()
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head=try_pop_head();
    return old_head?old_head->data:std::shared_ptr<T>();
}

template <typename T>
bool threadsafe_queue<T>::try_pop(T& value)
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head=try_pop_head(value);
    return old_head;
}

// wait and pop.
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> threadsafe_queue<T>::wait_and_pop()
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head=wait_pop_head();
    return old_head->data;
}

template <typename T>
void threadsafe_queue<T>::wait_and_pop(T& value)
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head=wait_pop_head(value);
}

// push.
template <typename T>
void threadsafe_queue<T>::push(T new_value)
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> new_data(
            std::make_shared<T>(std::move(new_value)));
    std::unique_ptr<node> p(new node);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> tail_lock(tail_mutex);
        tail->data=new_data;
        node* const new_tail=p.get();
        tail->next=std::move(p);
        tail=new_tail;
    }
    data_cond.notify_one();
}

// empty.
template <typename T>
void threadsafe_queue<T>::empty()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
    return (head.get()==get_tail());
}

#endif
```

There is one thing in the code I cannot reason about and it has appeared in two points. In `wait_pop_head(T& value)` and `try_pop_head(T& value)`, there is `value=std::move(*head->data);`. Basically to assign the dereferencing result of a `shared_ptr` to a reference, it passes it through `std::move`. I appreciate if you let me know why it should be done like this? Why shouldn't `value=*head->data;` be used instead?

Another question that came up in the comments is why should `std::shared_ptr` be used instead of `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Hmm, does the author describe why `node::data` is a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, rather than a `std::unique_ptr<T>`?

Comment: `Why shouldn't value=*head->data; be used instead?` Because a move, when available, is more efficient than a copy. Imagine that `T` is a large `vector`. `value=std::move(*head->data)` is an `O(1)` operation that just transfers the vector's internal pointers over; `value=*head->data` is an `O(n)` operation that physically copies all elements. Since `*head->data` is destroyed soon afterwards anyway, it's OK to steal its internals.

Comment: @ChrisCulter what the author says about using a `std::shared_ptr<T>` goes back to chapter 3: "The advantage of returning a pointer is that pointers can be freely copied without throwing an exception, so you've avoided Cargill's exception problem." and "For any interface that uses this option, `std::shared_ptr` would be a good choice of pointer type; not only does it avoid memory leaks, because the object is destroyed once the last pointer is destroyed, but the library is in full control of the memory allocation scheme and doesn't have to use `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @ChrisCulter It doesn't say why `std::shared_ptr` is preferred over `std::unique_ptr`; at least I couldn't find in the book.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks! If you provide your comment as an answer with the answer to the question I just added, I would accept it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing existing code. It belongs on the Code Review site.

Comment: @seh in here http://stackoverflow.com/tour it says "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." and one of the items they say "Ask about" is "Coding techniques". Using `std::move` is a "coding technique", as said in the comments, that avoids an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Fair enough. I appreciate you defending and refining the question. I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 1):

If type `T` defines a move assignment operator, then supplying an *rvalue reference* obtained via the call to `std::move()` will allow use of that more efficient operator, as opposed to forcing use a copying assignment operator.

If type `T` doesn't define a move assignment operator, it's fine to supply a `T&&` to its assignment operator, which will likely demand a parameter of type `const T&` or maybe just `T`. In either case, an argument of type `T&&` can be converted to the parameter type.

As far the use of `std::shared_ptr` rather than `std::unique_ptr`, I don't see why it's necessary either. It looks like it would be possible to return a `std::unique_ptr` from `try_pop()` and `wait_and_pop()`, moving the pointer out of the `threadsafe_queue::node` instance that's about to be destroyed. The only argument I can come up with is to allow callers of either of the "pop" functions to wind up with a sharable reference, thinking that to be the more flexible option. My cursory reading of the implementation doesn't show any case where two `threadsafe_queue::node` instances would ever point to the same "data" value, so I can't find any internal reason for that design choice.

Answer (score 0):

To the first one, if T has allocated dynamical memory, then the `move` can reduce much resource. And in the case, the funcation is named `*_pop_head`, that means the `data` of the head node should be treated useless after the calling.
So using `move` to transfer the ownership of T's dynamical memory to the target `T` object is reasonable.

To the second one, the only reason I can think is that if we want to have a `top` member function, we can hold the `data` of head node in more than one place.